# C# delete all the things inside the file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete some files from a specific directory. But there are some errors. 
I want my program to ignore these problems.

```
string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\prefetch");

foreach (string f in myFiles)
{
  File.Delete(f);
}
```

Comment: what is the error thrown ? show the stack trace pleace

Comment: sounds like a potential permission/elevation issue.

Comment: Yes How can I solve it?

Comment: @Blackhat You're asking individuals "how can I solve it" when you haven't given us the error in which you're trying to solve. If you can update your post and show _what_ the error actually is, we can help you much easier than taking random shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

By "errors" you mean thrown exceptions? `Directory.GetFiles` and `File.Delete` will throw exceptions if they can't find the directory/file or if you dont have permissions to access it, etc.
Since you want them ignored, you can just catch them and ignore them.

```
        try
        {
            string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\prefetch");
            foreach (string f in myFiles)
            {
                File.Delete(f);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

use this and you will delete the entire directory and respective files recursively

`Directory.Delete(@"C:\Windows\prefetch", true);`

Comment: This one will remove all thing in the directory including other directories with its files

Comment: @caxapexac yes, and he don´t specified the files to not be deleted